# Error while using mongoose.I am not able to run my code and i have no idea how to get mongod services running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsXyv.png)
I am repeatedly getting this error while running my code.I googled it and it had something to do with mongod services not running but i dont know how to get the services started.

Answer (score 0):

Your MongoDB database is most likely not running, from the path mentioned in your error, I am assuming you are running on Windows, I suggest you follow this guide: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#create-database-directory

You are going to have to create the data directories then start the database through your terminal.